# How to reduce total when the column is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Current Situation**

I have dynamic table, I can add/remove column and work on basic calculation
under price column displaying the total accumulation of each row.

[image]

But if I delete the second/third row the total number doesn't change.

[image]

**Expected Situation**

When I remove the row the total number automatically change accordingly

[image]

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/05Jde9AMAT4/o5ZAI23rUf1SxDYTHLrkOco0eyRV84=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead align="center" class="table table-primary">
        <tr>
            <th width="10%">amount</th>
            <th width="10%">Price</th>
            <th><a href="#" class="addRow btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="amount[]" class="amount" min="1" max="1000000" required="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="Price[]" class="Price" min="1" max="1000000000000" required="">
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="display:none;">
                <input type="number" name="total_price[]" class="total_price">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Price: </td>
            <td><b class="total"></b></td>
            <td style="border: none"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('tbody').delegate('.amount,.Price','keyup',function(){
            var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
            var amount=tr.find('.amount').val();
            var Price=tr.find('.Price').val();
            var total_price=(amount*Price);
            tr.find('.total_price').val(total_price);
            total();
        });

        function total(){
            var total=0;
            $('.total_price').each(function(i,e){
                var total_price=$(this).val()-0;
            total +=total_price;
        });
            $('.total').html("Rp. "+total);  
        }

        $('.remove').live('click',function(){
             var last=$('tbody tr').length;
        if(last==1){
            alert("You cannot delete the last row.");
        }
        else{
             $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        }
        });

        $('.addRow').on('click',function(){
            addRow();
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay You already have your answer in your question .. 
First you have the total calculating method.

```
function total(){
       var total=0;
       $('.total_price').each(function(i,e){
            var total_price=$(this).val()-0;
            total +=total_price;
        });
        $('.total').html("Rp. "+total);  
}
```

Then you also have the delete function
So just call the total function after the row has deleted.

```
$('.remove').live('click',function(){
        var last=$('tbody tr').length;
        if(last==1){
            alert("You cannot delete the last row.");
        }
        else{
             $(this).parent().parent().remove();
             //Here your row has been deleted.
             total();
        }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling the function total after removing an item

```
    $('.remove').live('click',function(){
         var last=$('tbody tr').length;
    if(last==1){
        alert("You cannot delete the last row.");
    }
    else{
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();
         // Call your function total here
    }
    });
```